# How do I serialize a list?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm new to `XmlSerializer`, I have a `List<T>` that I'd like to serialize like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<itens>
     <Item corret="0" order="&#x0;)">
     foo
     </Item>
     <Item corret="1" order="&#x1;)">
     baa
     </Item>
</itens>
    </ArrayOfItem>
```

instead of this (current output):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Item corret="0" order="&#x0;)">
 <test>foo</test>
 </Item>
 <Item corret="1" order="&#x1;)">
 <test>baa</test>
 </Item>
</ArrayOfItem>
```

i.e, remove the `test` tag, move its contents to `item` and place all the `item`s in the list inside the `itens` tag. How do I do this?

The class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Item
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int correctIndex { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int index { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("corret")]
    public string IsCorrect
    {
        get { return correctIndex == index ? "1" : "0"; }
        set { }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("order")]
    public string Order
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0})", ((char)index).ToString()); }
        set { }
    }

    [XmlElement("test")]
    public string text { get; set; }
}
```

I'm serializing using this:

```
new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Item>)).Serialize(Console.Out, list);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another class with property typed as `List<Item>`:

```
[Serializable]
public class Items
{
    [XmlArray("itens")]
    public List<Item> itens { get; set; }
}
```

and serialization code:

```
var list = new Items() { itens = new List<Item>() { new Item() { correctIndex = 10, index = 11, text = "asdasd" } } };
new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items)).Serialize(Console.Out, list);
```

To serialize `text` property as content of `Items` element instead of child `text` element replace `[XmlElement("text")]` with `[XmlText]`:

```
[XmlText]
public string text { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but about  remove the `test` tag and move its contents to `item`? i.e,  generate ` <Item corret="0" order="&#x0;)">
     foo
     </Item>` instead of ` <Item corret="0" order="&#x0;)">
 <test>foo</test>
 </Item>`

Comment: Didn't notice that it's different. Updated my answer.